# How to add constructor without parameter, in case the base class having the constructor with parameters

Tags: java

How to add a constructor without paramaters,In case the class extends some other class which is having parameterized constructor.

for example,

I am having a class B which extends A.

```
Class A {
  //Parameterized constructor
   A(int a,int b) {
     //some operation
   }
}


Class B extends A {
     //Constructor without paramaters
     B() {
     }   
}
```

Is it possible to create a empty constructor in Class B while extending Class A ?

Please let me know the details.

Thanks,
Thinesh

Comment: Yes, just add `super(0, 0)` in the `B` no-args constructor (in case you don't want to initialize `a` and `b` when creating a `B` instance).

Answer (score 2):

You should figure some value for the parameters required by the constructor of A.

```
class B extends A {
 //Constructor without paramaters
 B() {
   super(0,0);
 }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot ignore the parent's parameters.

Imagine that the parameters in the parent class are critical for it's functionality. It could be a compiled class that you don't necessarily knows how it works.

You can create an empty constructor in the child's class but when you call super you will have to pass the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class B extends A {

    public B() {
        super(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Note that if the parent class does not have a parameter-less constructor, you must provide sensible defaults yourself.